# Default values for arguments

Tags: python, function, default-arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

Consider the following function:

```
def foo(L = []):
  L.append(1)
  print L
```

Each time I call foo it will print a new list with more elements than previous time, e.g:

```
>>> foo()
[1]
>>> foo()
[1, 1]
>>> foo()
[1, 1, 1]
```

Now consider the following function:

```
def goo(a = 0):
  a += 1
  print a
```

When invoking it several times, we get the following picture:

```
>>> goo()
1
>>> goo()
1
>>> goo()
1
```

i.e. it does not print a larger value with every call.

What is the reason behind such seemingly inconsistent behavior?
Also, how is it possible to justify the counter-intuitive behavior in the first example, why does the function retain state between calls?

Comment: As well as many other answers on the same question.

Comment: Why are we all of a sudden getting this question a zillion times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default arguments are evaluated once when the function is defined.
So you get the same `list` object each time the function is called.

You'll also get the same `0` object each time the second function is called, but since `int` is immutable, when you add `1` as fresh object needs to be bound to a

```
>>> def foo(L = []):
...   print id(L)
...   L.append(1)
...   print id(L)
...   print L
... 
>>> foo()
3077669452
3077669452
[1]
>>> foo()
3077669452
3077669452
[1, 1]
>>> foo()
3077669452
3077669452
[1, 1, 1]
```

vs

```
>>> def foo(a=0):
...   print id(a)
...   a+=1
...   print id(a)
...   print a
... 
>>> foo()
165989788
165989776
1
>>> foo()
165989788
165989776
1
>>> foo()
165989788
165989776
1
```

Comment: That does not quite answer my question - I don't see why the second example (with an integer parameter) works as it does.

Comment: > You'll also get the same 0 object each time the second function is called -- then why can't I get the same [] object each time the first function is called?

Comment: @Grigory: Integers are immutable, `some_int += ...` creates a new integer instead of modifying `some_int`. `a` starts off with the same `0` each time the function is called without argument given, you just go on to change `a` to point to `0 + 1`.

Comment: In fact, you're getting the same object each time the first function is called. That's why it "remembers" its previous content.

Comment: @delnan thanks, that explains everything.