# Python: unable to explain class member list behaviour

Tags: python, list, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)
>   [Default values for arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938655/default-values-for-arguments)

I'm having trouble explaining how a list belonging to a class behaves.

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self, L=[]):
...         self.L = L
...
>>> a1 = A()
>>> a2 = A()
>>> a1.L.append("test")
>>> print a1.L
['test']
>>> print a2.L
['test']
```

In this example, how did a2.L get a value in it? I only added an item to the list in a1. How is it that they're sharing the list now.

Thanks,

Henry

Comment: This is so commonly asked - please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Answer (score 1):

A brief summary of all the comments you will get:

The problem is nothing to do with the class. It's because you're storing the values in the default argument of a function, and default arguments are stored *on the function objects*.